# Upgrading an Old Joomla 2.5 Site to 3.x Version

Tags: joomla-2.5, plugin, extensions, gantry

I have an old Joomla 2.5 site and am trying to upgrade it to the current version. My problem is I need to update some items but I'm not finding the old versions of them for doing that. They are:

- Gantry Framework v 4.1.32
- RokCandy Extension (RocketTheme) v 2.0.1
- RokBox Plugin (RocketTheme) v 2.0.8
- RokSprocket Module (RocketTheme) v 2.1.2
- RokGallery Extension (RocketTheme) v 2.29

What I would like to ask is: would anyone have these versions archived to provide me?

I asked the RocketTheme guys if they could provide me these versions but they said to me that is not possible, I don't know why. I would like to avoid to build up this website from the scratch so if there is any good soul out there that can help me I would be very grateful. :)

I think for having success on this task updating all the things in my old Joomla version is mandatory, but if someone has another solution I'm glad to hear his suggestion about.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] to better acquaint yourself with this community while you wait for support.

Answer (score 1):

Official support for Joomla 2.5 ended in 2014 and many extension developers have removed Joomla 2.5 versions of their extensions and templates from their websites so they can concentrate on supporting current versions.

If RocketTheme are unable to help, your best course of action may be to run a backup, disable third party extensions if needed, run the "mini-migration" from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.x and then upgrade all third party extensions to the latest versions.

It's possible other Joomla users may have the versions you are seeking but sourcing these from an untrusted source could introduce malware to your website.

Comment: Thank you very much, Neil. I'm going to try to do it in the way you're suggesting so.